# fwrite and fprintf not working in c

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io, network-programming

I have written a program to receive a piece of data from a network via socket and write it down to a file. I have used the following code for the purpose:

```
FILE *log;
log = fopen("time.log", "a"); 
fprintf(log,"HI all");
while(1)
{  
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
    printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    fflush(stdout);           
    while(1)
    {       
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(send_data,1000,stdin);
        send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
        bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
        recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
        char newln[2]="\n";
        int len=strlen(recv_data), len1=strlen(newln);
        fwrite(recv_data, len, 1, log);
        fwrite(newln, len1, 1, log);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}   
fclose(log);
```

If the file doesnot exist, the fopen succesfully creates the file, but after that nothing happens. No data is written into the file. neigther the "HI all" nor the received data. yes, the data is being received, i checked it by printing the received data. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. Operating platform is linux.

Comment: No, i used fflush(stdout). Should i remove it?

Comment: Yes, replace the `fflush(stdout)` with `fflush(log)` - your sample doesn't write anything to `stdout`, so the `fflush(stdout)` is not needed. The `fflush(log)` will cause anything that's still buffered to be written to `log`.

Comment: ok, got the code working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should check the return value of `fopen()` to ensure that, `log` is not `NULL`. Afterwards, you should use `fflush(log)` just before `fflush(stdout)`.

Another thing to mention is that you will never get out of the second `while(1)` loop, so you should also fix this.

```
if (bytes_received == 0) {
    /* client closed the connection */
    close(connected);
    break;
}
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
char newln[2]="\n";
```

Comment: I need the program to be executed continuously, so don't want to get out of the second while loop. Got the code working now. Thanks.

Comment: btw. since you do not write anything to `stdout` you can safely remove the `fflush(stdout)` part.

Comment: Yes, i replaced it with fflush(log).